# Gradebook program that tracks the performance of the students in the class, displays the students with highest and lowest grades

Tags: c++, performance, file

This program contains two classes, `Student` and `Course`, that will allow the user to analyze the performance of students in a particular course.

- `Student` class will contain private data members consisting of the students information (name, grades, letter grade, etc)
- `Course` class will act as part of the program that will manage the entire 
  class accordingly.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
ofstream toFile;
class Student
{
     private:
        string name;
        int project[6];
        int exam[2];
        int quiz[5];
        double project_avg;
        double exam_avg;
        double quiz_avg;
        int finalExam;
        double average;
        string grade;
     public: 
        Student();
        void get_student_scores();
        void compute_student_stats();
        void determine_student_grade();
        void display_student_name_gpa_grade();
        double student_average();
};

class Course
{
    private:
        Student student[7];
        int index_of_highest;
        int index_of_lowest;
    public:
        Course();
        ~Course();
        void get_grades();
        void evaluate_class();
        void determine_index_of_highest_lowest();
        void display_highest();
        void display_lowest();
        void display_stats();
};

Student::Student()
{
    name = " ";

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        project[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        exam[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        quiz[i] = 0;

    average, project_avg, exam_avg, quiz_avg = 0.0;
    finalExam = 0;
    grade = " ";
}

void Student::get_student_scores()
{
    try
    {
        cout << "\n Enter Student Name: \n";
        cin>>name;

        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Student project grade #"<<i+1<<":\n";
            cin>>project[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Student exam grade #"<<i+1<<":\n";
            cin>>exam[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Student quiz grade #"<<i+1<<":\n";
            cin>>quiz[i];
        }

        cout << "Enter final exam grade: \n";
        cin>>finalExam;    
    }

    catch(...)
    {
        cin.clear(); 
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout<<"Error, invalid input entered. \n";
    }
    return;
}

void Student::compute_student_stats()
{
    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        project_avg += project[i]; 
    project_avg = project_avg/6;
    cout << "Project Average = " << project_avg << "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        exam_avg += exam[i]; 
    exam_avg = exam_avg/2;
    cout << "Exam average = " << exam_avg << "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        quiz_avg += quiz[i]; 
    quiz_avg = quiz_avg/5;
    cout << "Quiz average = " << quiz_avg << "\n";

    average = (project_avg*0.25) + (exam_avg*0.4) + (quiz_avg*0.1) + (finalExam*0.25);
    cout << "Semester average = " << average << "\n"; 

    return;
}

void Student::determine_student_grade()
{
    grade = "0";
    if(average <= 100 && average >= 93)
        grade = "A";
    //range from 92 - 89
    else if(average >= 89)
        grade = "A-";
    //range from 88 - 87
    else if(average >= 87)
        grade = "B+";
    //range from 89 - 83
    else if(average >= 83)
        grade = "B";
    //range from 82 - 79
    else if(average >= 79)
        grade = "B-";
    //range from 78 - 77
    else if(average >= 77)
        grade = "C+";
    //range from 76 - 73
    else if(average >= 73)
        grade = "C";
    //range from 72 - 69
    else if(average >= 69)
        grade = "C-";
    //range from 68 - 67
    else if(average >= 67)
        grade = "D+";
    //range from 66 - 63
    else if(average >= 63)
        grade = "D";
    //range from 62 - 57   
    else if(average >= 57)
        grade = "D-";
    //range below 57    
    else if(average <= 57)
        grade = "F";

    cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    return;
}

void Student::display_student_name_gpa_grade()
{
    const int width1 = 19;
    const int width2 = 17;

    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
    cout << left << setw(width1) << "Student = " << name;
    cout << right << setw(width2) << "Average = " << average;
    cout << right << setw(width2) << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";

    toFile.open("student.txt",ios::app);
    toFile<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
    toFile << left << setw(width1) << "Student = " << name;
    toFile << right << setw(width2) << "Average = " << average;
    toFile << right << setw(width2) << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    toFile.close();
    return;
}

double Student::student_average()
{
    return average;
}



Course::Course()
{
    index_of_highest = 0;
    index_of_lowest = 0;
}
Course::~Course()
{
    cout << "Course Object is going out of existence.";
}
void Course::get_grades()
{
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
        student[i].get_student_scores();    
    return;
}

void Course::evaluate_class()
{
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        student[i].compute_student_stats();
        student[i].determine_student_grade();
    }
    return;
}

void Course::determine_index_of_highest_lowest()
{
    int tempHighest = 0; 
    int tempLowest = 100;

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        if(student[i].student_average() > tempHighest)
        {
            tempHighest = student[i].student_average();
            index_of_highest = i;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        if(student[i].student_average() < tempLowest)
        {
            tempLowest = student[i].student_average();
            index_of_lowest = i;
        }
    }
    return;
}


/*==============================================================================
 when displaying the name, grade, and gpa, The very first student, (student[0])
 is not being sent to the txt file "student.txt"
==============================================================================*/
void Course::display_stats()
{    
    for (int i=0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        student[i].display_student_name_gpa_grade();
    }
}

void Course::display_highest()
{
    student[index_of_highest].display_student_name_gpa_grade();
        return;
}

void Course::display_lowest()
{    
    student[index_of_lowest].display_student_name_gpa_grade();
        return;
}

void describeProgram()
{
    cout<<"This program will serve as a grade book for seven students who are"
          " participating in a course, \n and will also analyze the performances"
          "of the students as well. Each student will have six projects (worth 25%"
          " collectively), \n two midterm exams (worth 20% each), and five quizzes (worth 10%"
          " collectively), and a final exam (worth 25%). \n The program will calculate"
          " the class average and will also display the student with the highest"
          " and lowest grade.";  
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Course courseObj;

    describeProgram();
    courseObj.get_grades();
    courseObj.evaluate_class();
    courseObj.determine_index_of_highest_lowest();

    toFile.open("student.txt",ios::out);

    toFile<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2)<<endl;
    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2)<<endl;  

    courseObj.display_stats();
    cout << "\n";
    toFile << "\n";

    cout<<"The name, average, and grade of the best student in the class is:\n";
    toFile<<"The name, average, and grade of the best student in the class is:\n";  
    courseObj.display_highest();

    cout<<"The name, average, and grade of the poorest student in the class is:\n";
    toFile<<"The name, average, and grade of the poorest student in the class is:\n";
    courseObj.display_lowest();
    toFile.close();
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me be the first to say:

## Don't say `using namespace std;`

You use of specific numbers in the array sizes gets my attention.  Then,

```
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    project[i] = 0;
```

Here you are assuming you know how many elements there are, and repeating the "magic number" rather than at least using a named constant.

But, to zero out a primitive C-style array you don't write a legacy `for` loop anyway.  Use

```
std::fill(std::begin(project),std::end(project), 0);
```

but that's rather awkward when I just want the whole thing, so I'd actually use

```
boost::range::fill (project, 0);
```

**but**, just don’t!

Declare `project` as a type that will automatically initialize its elements.

```
int project[6];  // original
```

becomes

```
std::array<int,6> project;
```

Likewise for the other array looks.

You also have `name = " ";` (one space) and I don't know if that's what you really meant.  I’ll assume for now that you mean for the name to be empty (that is, blank).

Strings initialize themselves.  If you wanted to initialize to something other than empty, you would put it as an *initializer* in the constructor, not an *assignment* in the body of the constructor.  That’s true about all the stuff in the constructor — nothing you have there should actually be in the body!

For the plain int and double values, you can use inline data member inititializers to good effect here.

```
⋮  // inside the class definition
double project_avg = 0.0;
double exam_avg = 0.0;
⋮
```

now there is nothing left of your constructors, so get rid of the whole thing.

---

For `get_student_scores`, this is not something we would normally do.  This kind of prompt and line-read is not realistic for real-world programs.  However, you might be getting input from a file or something like that.

Point is, you don’t want to use a legacy `for` loop, you don’t want to use indexes on your array one by one, yet printing out the index as part of the prompt means you need to know the number.  That teaches you an **anti-pattern** which is why I’m harping on it as a teaching example.

Let me change it a little bit but keep the manual input with prompts

```
for (auto& grade : project) {
    cout << "Enter a grade\n";
    cin >> grade;
}
```

---

for `compute_student_stats`, you are also using legacy `for` loops and manual implementation of the work.  **Know your std algorithms.**  That’s a specific case of *know your libraries*, which is a very important thing.

As before, I’ll use [Boost’s version](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0_beta1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms.html) instead of [std](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

```
{
using boost::range::accumulate;
project_avg = accumulate(project) / double(project.size());
// ditto for the others
```

Another thing to note:  The sum gives me an integer, so I have to explicitly convert one of the arguments in the division to `double` or I’ll get integer division.  Adding the `int`s will be faster than converting each `int` to a `double` and adding those, the way you have it.

---

`determine_student_grade` is very repetitive.  There is no built-in way to specify this like a `case` statement, but I would use a data structure with the cutoffs and grades rather than a cascade of `if`’s.

Let’s not worry about that for now; that is more advanced.

---

`Student::student_average()` should be **`const`**.

And trivial functions like this are normally listed inline in the class definition.

---

`Course` constructor:

Same notes as before.  Use inline initializers in the class definition, and don’t even write a constructor.  And when you do need a constructor, know the difference between initialization and assignment.

For the destructor, I wondered why you even needed one.  In the body I see you are instrumenting it — that’s indeed a reason to need one.

---

Continuing, I see the same issues.  loops, writing `std::max` by hand instead of knowing the library, etc.

You don’t need a bare return at the end of a function.

Various print-out functions that don’t change the object should be `const`.

---

I don’t know what `system("PAUSE");` is about.  It’s non-portable.  If it stops the screen from scrolling, why do you need that when you are done and not going to print anything more?

---

`toFile` should not be global.  Define it where it is opened, and pass it into functions that output.

Answer (score 1):

I skipped `determine_student_grade` in my first answer.  I come back to it now.

First, rather than knowing about the grade and letter members of the student class, it should be a separate function that the student class then can use.  It is a function that takes a number as input and produces a letter grade as output.  It doesn’t have anything else to do with the specifics of that class, so it should not know about anything else.

The only thing it needs to know is passed as input.  The result is returned.

```
// not a member of any class
const char* letter_grade (int score)  {
```

Second, the code you wrote is highly repetitive.  When you have a whole bunch of duplicated blocks like that where only a couple values are changing, pull those values out into a data structure and then **loop over it**.

Without a lot of fuss, I just used a primitive array of pairs.

```
constexpr std::pair<int, const char*> gradechart[] = {
    { 100, "A+" },
    { 93, "A" }, 
    { 89, "A-" }, 
    { 87, "B+" }, 
    { 83, "B" }, 
    { 79, "B-" }, 
    { 77, "C+" },
    { 73, "C"}, 
    { 69, "C-" }, 
    { 67, "D+" }, 
    { 63, "D"}, 
    { 57, "D-"}, 
    { -1, "F" }
};
```

Knowing I was going to loop over this and stop when I got a match, I did not want to worry about special cases inside that loop if it’s before the first element or still not found at the last element.  So I put **precondition** checks explicitly into the function.

```
if (score > 9999) throw std::invalid_argument("That's excessive extra credit!");
if (score < 0) throw std::invalid_argument("Can't score worse than nothing!");
```

Now, at last, do the real work.  Finding where a value should fit inside a sorted collection is something people have a need for, in general.  You would think that is already in the library, right?

Finding either the match or the spot where an element should be inserted if it wasn’t found is a primitive thing used to maintain a sorted collection.  These are [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), `upper_bound`, and `equal_range`.

However, as usual I’ll use Boost’s version instead of the std version, but this time I have another reason for doing so.  Besides being able to just give it the whole array without doing the begin/end stuff, Boost’s handles the key being a different type than the element.  It’s silly to create a dummy record just to compare the key field!  I want to search for an `int`, not a pair whose first value is an int.

```
// This is the actual meat of the function
auto lb= boost::range::lower_bound (gradechart, score,
    [](const auto& row, int val) { return row.first > val; });
```

Now since I did preconditions, I *really* do not expect `lb` to be invalid.  But I added a check anyway:

```
if (lb == std::end(gradechart)) throw std::logic_error ("should not happen");
```

And I’m done.

```
    return lb->second;
}
```

---

Now to test it and demonstrate it, I wrote a simple `main`.

```
using std::cout;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int count= argc-1;
    char** arg = argv+1;
    while (count--) {
        auto num = atoi (*arg++);
        cout << "number: " << num << "  letter: " << letter_grade(num) << '\n';
    }
}
```

And I ran it with *critical test cases* that check the edges to make sure the chart is being used as intended: 57 is a D- but 56 is an F.  (Note that I added an A+ which is 100 or better).

```
[prompt]graderange.exe 105 100 99 89 57 56 89 1 0
number: 105  letter: A+
number: 100  letter: A+
number: 99  letter: A
number: 89  letter: A-
number: 57  letter: D-
number: 56  letter: F
number: 89  letter: A-
number: 1  letter: F
number: 0  letter: F
```

Comment: Wow, very informative stuff my professor seemed to never teach.....Guess you can't learn everything in the classroom. Although i was wondering why in the `display_stats` method, the very first student would never be written inside to the txt file. For example, if the first student was named jake. Jake would never be written to the file. But it would be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Re your school: in 2011 every C++ book became obsolete.  You don't learn *fluency* in the classroom, but through practice. Knowing “DRY” (don't repeat yourself) *should* be taught.  You could have written a loop using 1998 conventions, but didn't.

Comment: @Zachariah first one not showing up in the file: how strange.  Did you try stepping through it in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I copied your source and ran it myself.

First of all, did you notice that there is something seriously wrong?!

> Student =          Baker       Average = -22368577576085144521364296908912192942446188117496865356775424.00  Letter Grade = F

You have a mistake in the `Student` constructor:

```
//  average, project_avg, exam_avg, quiz_avg = 0.0;  // BUG !!
average= project_avg= exam_avg= quiz_avg = 0.0;
```

You set quiz_avg to 0.0, but the other words you used have no effect!  See the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) for what you actually did.

---

The reason the first student is not appearing in the file is because you got confused over what you were doing with the `toFile` variable.

Within the function, it looks well (though strange):

```
toFile.open("student.txt", ios::app);
    ⋮
toFile.close();
```

For a program that simply prints the output to a file, opening and closing for each part doesn’t make sense.  Just open it and use it.  But this is useful for something like a log file where you have occasional output.

Now here’s the problem:  In `main` you have

```
toFile.open("student.txt", ios::out);
```

and never close it there.

So, the first time `display_student_name_gpa_grade` is called, you get an error from `toFile.open` (which you never check for) because it’s already open!  Then you close it, which resets the *bad* condition.

---

Another thing to learn about C++ is [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) (also read [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) on this subject).  This is a fundamental strength of C++ and it should be used to good effect wherever resources are used.

So, don’t have a global file object that you open and close at various points in time.  Declare the variable when you are ready to open it and use the constructor, not an `.open` call, to open it.  When it goes out of scope, it is closed, so you never explicitly close it.

In this case, you should define it in `main` where you are opening it now, and pass it into functions that need to use it:

```
ofstream toFile {"student.txt"};
if (!toFile) throw runtime_error ("Could not open the file");

courseObj.display_stats (toFile);
```

I see that in your existing code, `toFile` will have been closed when it returns to `main` so `toFile << "\n";` will also not go anywhere.

---

minor:  use the character `'\n'` instead of a one-character string `"\n"` when printing your newlines.